# Water conductivity measurement AC, interfacing with arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, ac, meter

I want to implementate this device, mentioned in the title.

The problem is how to correctly build the " read out device" that is clearly a wheatsone bridge?

But in AC, the problem is the signal conditioning for a frecuency between 1-20khz probably I suppose that I need to use an OP AMP stage and an AC to DC meter after it.

Nevertheless the whole thing needs to be very acurrate. Any advices?
[image]

The final goal is to interface with arduino.

Thanks!

Comment: Define very accurate.  I made a little circuit for measuring water conductivity a few months ago.  AC drive voltage, SS probes in water, TIA opamp circuit to measure the current.  Done.  (Well the hard part is the calibration.. I didn't do that.. but easy to see changes when a pinch of salt was added to the water.)

Comment: very accurate is that the device no need to be so acurate like the comercial devices that cost arround 200$ but enough for monitoring the conductivity . I can not give you more dates I still dont have the aknowledge of the magnitudes.

Comment: can you share your circuit? please?

Answer (score 1):

Sure the TIA (trans-impedance amp) converts a current to a voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpszDW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V-water is not a battery,  it's the electro-chemical response of the water/electrode.  I'm not sure exactly what it is... you'll have to play around with the frequency.

Comment: thats true, water is not a battery deppending on frecuency it´s more capacitive or lees, but in this frecuency only have a resistive behaviour